# Dynamic search like stackoverflow for django

Tags: python, django, search, django-queryset

Does anyone know what plugin (with Django) is *best* to handle dynamic searches like StackOverflow's? Something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching):

```
<input type="text" value="how to [django] or [python] duplicate:yes is:answer" style="width: 50%">
```

I just think about complex queries.

```
query = request.GET.get('q')

text_query = # what regex here?
tags_query = # 
is_duplicate = re.search(r'(?P<duplicate>\w+)', query)

Question.objects.filter(...)
Answer.objects.filter(...)
```

Comment: no plugin is really necessary. It could relatively easily be handled with regex. Are you asking how the above query could be handled as an example?

Comment: @Jonathan ah yes... can you provide an example how to do that? something how to find `text_query = 'how to'` and else..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query = "how to [django] or [python] or [mu] duplicate:yes is:answer"

tags = re.search(r'\[(\w+)\](( or \[(\w+)\])+)?', query)
colons = re.findall(r'\w+:\w+', query)

search = query.replace(tags.group(), '')
for colon in colons:
    search = search.replace(colon, '')

print(search) # how to
```

Then you can process tags and colons separately for querying.

If you want to search the questions database for all of the terms in the search query you could do something like this. It will find all text that contains all the search terms.

```
search = search.split()

db_query = Q(text__icontains=search[0])
for term in search[1:]:
    db_query = db_query | Q(text__icontains=term)

Question.objects.filter(db_query)
```

Comment: how about 2 or 3 queries? eg: `query = "left side [django] or [python] or [mu] duplicate:yes is:answer right side"`, so here we got `'left side'` and `'right side'`.. if I following your answer I got `'left side    right side'` _(with blank space)_. how I can identify `'left side    right side'` one by one.

Comment: @sanca would the right side have any semantic meaning? If you make the query in stackoverflow it doesn't care. It'll search for for entries containing `left side right side`

Comment: @SancaKembang I updated the answer a bit more for how the query would look on the database side of things.

Comment: hmm I see.. I think it doesn't perfect if with full text like `title__icontains='left side right side'`, It should be `title__icontains='left side'` and `title__icontains='right side'`.. like this [picture](https://i.imgur.com/y0kei1H.png) results of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=left+side+%5Bdjango%5D+or+%5Bpython%5D+or+%5Bmu%5D+duplicate%3Ayes+is%3Aanswer+right+side)

Comment: the output of `search.split()` is `['how', 'to', 'right', 'side']`

Comment: @SancaKembang Stack overflow searches for the words separately: http://imgur.com/a/7C490 If you look further down you'll see more examples of this. left side and right side just happens to belong to each other quite often because of the english language.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154062/discussion-between-jonathan-and-sanca-kembang).